# Load OS X kext in the early boot process

Tags: macos, kernel, boot, kernel-extension

I have a working OSX kernel extension which I would like to be automatically loaded at boot time as early as possible. The kext is using [KAUTH](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/technotes/tn2127/_index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS10003591-CH1-SUBSECTION11) for monitoring access on a specific path so it seems to me there won't be anything that will request it to be loaded into the kernel. In this case, copying it in `/Library/Extensions` (at least since Yosemite this is the recommended path for third-party extensions) won't solve my problem.

Is there a possibility to achieve this, whether or not by modifying the code or through some auxiliary configuration?

I already read about using a launchd daemon to use kextload in order to load the extension, as specified in [this question](https://superuser.com/questions/47233/how-can-i-force-a-mac-os-x-kext-to-load-prior-to-login), but in my case, I want it to be loaded as early as possible.

**Update:**
I am using a "generic" kernel extension (linked against BSD library) and not an I/O Kit based one.
I want my extension to be loaded before `launchd` is started.

Comment: Hi, I've got the same issue except that I also want my kext to be loaded in safe boot mode.. Does your driver loaded in safe boot as well ?

Comment: I can load the driver in safe boot as well, all thanks to the `OsBundleRequired` key set in the `Info.plist` file. I'm currently using `Root` but I remember working with other values as well. Choose what best suits you from one of the values mentioned in the [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Darwin/Conceptual/KEXTConcept/Articles/infoplist_keys.html)

Comment: when you say "safe mode" do you mean the recovery mode ? because I saw that when loading from recovery mode (pressing command+R in startup), my kext doesn't even found in `/Library/Extensions`

Comment: I was mistakably confused between `safe boot` and `recovery mode` which appears to be 2 different states

Comment: It appears the simple presence of the `OsBundleRequired` property is enough for the kext to load in safe boot mode.

Comment: that's right, but in `recovery mode` it's totally different story. it seems like this mode has partition of it's own, and you need to copy your kext there.. but I don't know how to access this partition from the normal mode

Comment: Ironically, it appears the only value for the `OsBundleRequired` property which does not load the kext in safe boot is `Safe Boot`

Comment: Related to the recovery mode, I don't think you'll be able to write your kext there since the recovery partition is marked as read-only.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You don't explicitly state it in the question, but I infer from the context that you're using a "generic" kernel extension (in contrast to an I/O kit based one)? These are only loaded either because another kext depends on them, or because they are explicitly loaded via kextutil/kextload or the KextManager API.

Contrast this to I/O Kit kexts, which are loaded on-demand when one of their personality dictionaries matches a registered service in the IO registry. This is usually for driving specific devices, but various non-hardware-dependent system services use the mechanism to match the 'IOResources' nub ([documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/DeviceDrivers/Conceptual/IOKitFundamentals/Matching/Matching.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP0000015-BAJEICBG)) which turns up during early boot so any kexts listing it as a provider for a personality also get loaded on boot.

So the solution would be to modify your kext to provide an IOService which matches the IOResources nub. The service itself doesn't really need to do anything if your userspace component already uses another interface to communicate with the kext.

If you don't want to change the kext's code itself, you could possibly create a dummy kext which does this, but declares your main kext as a dependency. This latter method isn't particularly elegant, but should work if for some reason modifying the existing kext is not possible. (Although you'll likely need to modify the info.plist)

Comment: Yes, I am trying to use a generic kernel extension and not one depending on I/O Kit, I will update the question. Interesting enough, even I make an I/O Kit dummy extension which lists in the `Info.plist` file my generic kext as a dependency, the loading is done after launchd is started, contrary to what I am trying to achieve.

Comment: To get your kext to be added to the prelinked kernel, you can abuse the OSBundleRequired property. This tells the OS that it's required for booting; normally used by storage device drivers etc. See https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Conceptual/KEXTConcept/Articles/infoplist_keys.html for details.

Comment: I was aware of the `OSBundleRequired` property. I solved my problem by changing the extension to an I/O Kit based one with the mentioned property set accordingly. I had some problems with the naming, it appears that the name for the `IOKitPersonality` dictionary is required to be identical to the extension name.

Comment: If by name you mean bundle ID, then yes.

Answer (score 0):

If the kext is derived from IOKit and resides in */Library/Extensions* clear the cache and it will be automatically loaded at boot. You clear the cache by calling

```
kextcache -f -update-volume /
```

Comment: @TheDarkNight I already tried to rebuild the cache using the `kextcache` command you mentioned, with and without removing all content from `/System/Library/Caches/com.apple.kext.caches` before running the command, none of the combinations worked.

Comment: It's designed to work this way. Have you checked the system logs to see if it reports any issues about loading your kext?

Comment: This will only work if the kext is based on I/O kit matching. I'll write up a separate answer to explain in more detail.

Comment: Note also that Apple recommends using `touch /Library/Extensions/` command  (or `touch /System/Library/Extensions/` pre-10.9)  for triggering a kernel cache refresh, at least in production (install scripts etc.).